# returning a static variable from a function

Tags: c

The following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "string.h"

int main() { 
    char *s ; 
    char *fun() ;   
    s = fun() ;    
    printf ("%s",s) ;
    return 0; 
} 

char *fun() {  
    char buffer[30] ;
    strcpy ( buffer, "RAM - Rarely Adequate Memory" ) ; 
    return ( buffer ) ;  
}
```

Gives unexpected results whenever the size of buffer is changed and does not give the required answer.

By making char `buffer[30]` `static` the code prints `"RAM-Rarely Adequate Memory"` which is right.
How does static make a difference?

Comment: buffer is automatic so it gets cleaned up from stack when you return from the function.

Comment: Make your life easier: use `std::string`

Comment: You should enable warnings, e.g. at least `-Wall` in gcc which would warn you about e.g. returning addresses of local variables and many other nasty problems.

Comment: your code is closer to C than to C++, in C++ you should use <iostream> for std::cout (instead of printf) and <string> for std::string (instead of bare char*)

Answer (score 4):

(automatic) local variables are destroyed as soon as you leave the block where they were declared. Keeping a reference to them is just as wrong as keeping a pointer to a deallocated memory block.

static (local) variables have the same lifespan as the program that declares them.

Implementation-wise, a static variable is allocated in the same space as the global variables.
Semantically, it is still only visible inside the block where it was declared, but it retains its value outside its declaration scope.

Beware, though. Retaining a reference to a static variable might have unpleasant side effects.

For instance, each call to your function will reset the string to its initial value, so the callers should make their own copies of it if they don't want any other piece of the code to be able to mess with the value they got from your function.

Answer (score 2):

You're returning a local variable, which is triggering undefined behaviour. `char buffer[30]` is a stack variable, so when the function exits, it goes out of scope, and is cleaned up.

Making it `static` means it is does not go out of scope when the function exits, and thus works correctly.

In C, one would usually fix this by passing in a buffer to write to:

```
void fun(char *buffer, size_t len)
{
    // Write some stuff into buffer
}
```

In C++, use `std::string`.

Comment: "...and thus works correctly.": I'd add "as long as you don't make a second call (and the contents change)".

Comment: @Mario you can make that clause a part of the contract. See `strtok`

Answer (score 1):

Without `static`, the variable `buffer` passes out of scope as soon as the function `fun` terminates. The `main` routine is then left holding a pointer to a defunct variable, and dereferencing it causes **Undefined Behavior**.

Answer (score 1):

`buffer` is a local variable, wich is destroyed one time `fun` ends.

if `buffer` is `static`, is always in the program.

if you want that `fun` return an array, you can use dynamic memory.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"string.h"

int main( ){

    char *s;    
    char *fun();

    s = fun();    
    printf ("%s",s);

    // in c pure 
    //free(s);
    // in c++
    delete s;
}


char *fun(){         
    // in c pure
    //char * buffer = (char*) malloc(30*sizeof(char));        
    // in c++
    char *buffer = new char[30];

    strcpy ( buffer, "RAM - Rarely Adequate Memory" );        
    return ( buffer ) ;    
}
```

Comment: This was tagged with C++, you should at the least be using new/delete, and at best discussing shared pointers.

Comment: Also is tagged in C. I start with c and sometimes forget that is posible to do new char[30].

Answer (score 1):

First, pointer to local variable should not be returned.

Second, `auto` local variable will disappear as soon as the code block (function) exits. But `static` local variable will stay there till the whole program is ended. For the same reason, you can access that `static` local variable next time you get into that code block.

Comment: You mean **pointers** to local variables should not be returned.

Answer (score 0):

The `buffer` without `static` is placed on the processor's [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29).  When `fun` ends, the stack memory that was used for this function is freed.

But this freeing does not actually change the contents of these used stack memory locations.  This means that the string you copied to `buffer` will initially still be there.

As the program progresses, this freed stack space (which was first used by your `buffer`), will get used for other stuff.  But it's hard to tell when this will happen, as it all depends on how the compiler planned to use stack space.

In theory, your program could have nicely printed out `RAM - Rarely Adequate Memory`; when this part of the stack were not overwritten.  So actually you are lucky, as you could have had a latent bug that could bite at a later stage (for example after you started adding code to `main()`, or changed compiler options for example.)